# Socket not working on jQuery Mobile events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, firefox-os

I've just started developing an application with javascript for fxos using jQuery Mobile and already got stuck with a framework related problem. For my app I need to use tcp communication provided by mozilla API (mozTCPSocket), it works well when I run it outside from JQM events, but when I do the socket.open() call from a JQM event (eg. pageshow) it looks like the socket object is being killed after each call.

Here is my code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    'use strict';

    var socket;
    var host = "someserver";
    var port = 6667;
    //connect(); // when calling from here, connection works fine

    $(document).bind("pageshow", function(e) {
        if (typeof e.currentTarget.URL==="string") {
            var haystack = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(e.currentTarget.URL);
            var needle = /^#server/;
            if (haystack.hash.search(needle)!==-1) {
                connect(); // ...from here is failing
            }
        }
    });

    function connect() {
        socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(host,port);
    }

    socket.ondata = function (event) {
        var data = event.data;
        var lines = data.split('\r\n');
        for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
          if (lines[i].length>0) console.log(lines[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: What version of JQM are you using? Does it hit other code inside that event?

Comment: There should be no difference on where you connect, unless an actual different page gets loaded after `pageshow` event. So you sure you hit the connect logic through that event?

Comment: @Archon I'm using jQM 1.4.3 and jQuery 2.1.1 ¿Should I downgrade?

Comment: @JanJongboom It's passing through connect(), the only difference is when connect() is called from pageshow event, the socket.ondata event is never getting called

Comment: Try changing the `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',` to `document.addEventListener('mobileinit',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's certainly wrong here is this:

```
socket.ondata = function (event) {
    var data = event.data;
    var lines = data.split('\r\n');
    for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
      if (lines[i].length>0) console.log(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

You're setting the `ondata` method on an `undefined` object. Which means that any call to `connect()` later won't have any effect anyway. Also as you're defining a method of an `undefined` object, the method above probably is crashing.

You should rewrite your code to something like this.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    'use strict';

    var socket;
    var host = "someserver";
    var port = 6667;
    //connect(); // when calling from here, connection works fine

    $(document).bind("pageshow", function(e) {
        if (typeof e.currentTarget.URL==="string") {
            var haystack = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(e.currentTarget.URL);
            var needle = /^#server/;
            if (haystack.hash.search(needle)!==-1) {
                connect(); // ...from here is failing
            }
        }
    });

    function connect() {
        socket = navigator.mozTCPSocket.open(host, port);
        socket.ondata = onData;
    }

    function onData (event) {
        var data = event.data;
        var lines = data.split('\r\n');
        for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
          if (lines[i].length>0) console.log(lines[i]);
        }
    }
});
```